# How do I concatenate two lists while taking elements 1 by 1

Tags: python, list

How do I concatenate two lists while taking elements 1 by 1 in Python?

Example:

```
listone = [1, 2, 3]
listtwo = [4, 5, 6]
```

Expected outcome:

```
>>> joinedlist
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just `list_comprehensions` and no other fancy library you can do this:

```
In [825]: [j for i in zip(listone, listtwo) for j in i]                                                                                                                                                     
Out[825]: [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

`zip` the lists and flatten with [`itertooos.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(zip(listone, listtwo)))
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way:

```
x = []

for a in zip(listone,listtwo):
    x.extend(a)
x
```

Or if you want some black magic with chain from itertools:

```
list(chain(*zip(listone,listtwo)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
joinedlist = [x for pair in zip(listone, listtwo) for x in pair]
```

Comment: I just realised that this is the same as @Mayank Porwal's great answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

U have many choice to get the output you expected.

1. Use nested looping

```
x = []
for a in zip(listone, listtwo):
    for b in a:
        x.append(b)
```

2. Single loop, just append and using index for a

```
x = []
for a in zip(listone, listtwo):
    x.append(a[0])
    x.append(a[1])
```

3. And single line looping(more simple)

```
x = [x for i in zip(listone, listtwo) for x in i]
```

If u print `x` for each point, the output will be: `[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]`